# Windows search cannot find files in current directory

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, files, find, search, indexing

We have a windows server 2012 r2 that has the file server role and windows search installed.
The drives with the shared folders are indexed and the shares folders are mapped on all clients.
I can search the mapped drive for some files but it does not find them. Both on windows 7 and windows 10 clients. 
I can navigate to the folder where the files are, see them in front of me in windows explorer and do the search again and still don't find them. 
I can do the same directly on the server and it still does not find the files in the same folder where I Don the search. 
The files are from the 4th so they are 6 days old today. 
I can find files in some folders so the search is working sometimes. 
The indexing is enabled for all folders on the drive, and the system has correct folder permissions. 
Any idea what is wrong here? 
I am going nuts here...

Comment: from your server, can you bring up the "Indexing Options" control panel? It should have a status at the top that shows "Indexing complete." or some other status. Also, you can verify that your server is indexing all the folders you'd like it to.

Comment: Indexing is complete and all the drives with shares on it are checked..

Comment: What is an example file name and an example search term?

Comment: File name 117765522.pdf and search for 1177 in same directory as the file

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your search index is corrupt.  If that's the case, the best option is to rebuild the index.

```
Control Panel --> Indexing Options --> Advanced --> Rebuild
```

It will probably take some time to rebuild the index.

Comment: If it is corrupt, can some search work or is all search not working?

Comment: @NiclasH either can happen.  In my experience, older files will be found but newer ones won't be added to the index.

Comment: I did a reindex, still does not work. Also did multiple reboots. Also removed windows search service, rebooted and added it again. Still not resolved..

Answer (score 0):

I now know what caused it.
Deduplication. Indexing does not work on deduplicated files.
I will try to create a script that undedup directories, index them and then deduplicate them again.